# Need help on Problem in using c# .net 4.0 realtime chart in windows form application

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, charts

I have a windows form which has 1 button (for simplicity).

On clicking this button, I start an algorithm in a separate background thread using ParameterizedThreadStart.

Now this algorithm produces output at regular time intervals which needs to be displayed in a chart.

1. If i init the chart in MainForm and pass this object to algorithm thread, then it doesnt allow and says chart's allocation and access are cross-thread.
2. If i have chart object inside algo class, then it doesnt display the chart ticks. Only a blank  form shows up (that too by doing  _chart.Show()) and no ticks displayed.

Also, how to AddPoint to the chart, I used chart.Invoke(chart.AddPointDelegate, params) in the 2nd case, but it gets stuck at  Invoke.

Please help me with a way out.

**EDIT:**

```
    public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _getChartDataDelegate = AddTickToChart;
    }

    public AddTickChartDelegate _getChartDataDelegate;

    public void AddTickToChart(ChartTickPoint point)
    {
        DateTime x = point.X;
        double y = point.Y;
        object[] parameters = { x, y };


        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {// this prevents the invoke loop
            this.Invoke(new Action<ChartTickPoint>(_chart.chartDelegate), new object[] {  point }); // invoke call for _THIS_ function to execute on the UI thread
        }
        else
        {
            //function logic to actually add the datapoint goes here
            //_chart.Invoke(_chart.chartDelegate, parameters);
            _chart.AddTick(point);
        }
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(MyUtils.RunAlgo));
        AlgoData algoData = new AlgoData(myFile, _getChartDataDelegate);
        thread.Start(algoData);
    }
    // MyForm ends

    // Intermediate static Util class to run algo
    MyUtils.RunAlgo(object obj)
    {
       // new Algo
       // Get delegate from algoData obj
       algo.Run(delegateInTheMyForm);

    }

    // Algo class's Run
    Run(AddTickChartDelegate delegateInTheMyForm)
    {
        delegateInTheMyForm(point);
    }

    // Chart class
    public AddTickChartDelegate chartDelegate;

    public void AddTick(ChartTickPoint point)
    {
        DateTime timeStamp = point.X;
        double y = point.Y;

        foreach (Series ptSeries in chart1.Series)
        {
            AddNewPoint(timeStamp, y, ptSeries);
        }
    }
```

Here again i am getting cross-thread issue at this.Invoke(new Action..) in MyForm class.

Further,

```
If i replace this.Invoke(Action..) with chart.Invoke(..)
if (this.InvokeRequired)
{
_chart.Invoke(_chart.chartDelegate, point);
// instead of Action...
}
```

then it goes through , but the chart form is not responsive and is blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a function for adding datapoints in your form class

For example:

```
public void addDataPoint(YourDataClass entity)
{
    if(this.InvokeRequired)
    {// this prevents the invoke loop
       this.Invoke(new Action<YourDataClass>(addDataPoint),new object[]{entity}); // invoke call for _THIS_ function to execute on the UI thread
    }
    else{
       //function logic to actually add the datapoint goes here
       chartControl.Series[0].Points.AddXY(entity.X,entity.Y); // assuming your dataclass has the members X and Y and you are using the first Series on a MSChart control
    }
}
```

You can call this function from your worker thread since it will invoke the UI thread to avoid cross-thread access

So... yes, your worker will need to have a reference to that function... if you want to keep your algo class knowledge of the form to a minimum, you can build an object that holds the reference to the form (cast to ISynchronizedInvoke) and the delegate (addDataPoint) so the worker keeps separated from the UI.

//EDIT: Complete example Form

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace ExampleApplication
{
    public class Form1 : Form
    {

        #region designer-generated-code
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea chartArea1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea();
            System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Legend legend1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Legend();
            System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series();
            this.chart1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.chart1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // chart1
            // 
            this.chart1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
                        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
                        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            chartArea1.Name = "ChartArea1";
            this.chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea1);
            legend1.Name = "Legend1";
            this.chart1.Legends.Add(legend1);
            this.chart1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
            this.chart1.Name = "chart1";
            series1.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
            series1.Legend = "Legend1";
            series1.Name = "Series1";
            this.chart1.Series.Add(series1);
            this.chart1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(733, 192);
            this.chart1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.chart1.Text = "chart1";
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(620, 210);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(125, 40);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.button1.Text = "button1";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(757, 262);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.chart1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.chart1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        private System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart chart1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
        #endregion

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void AddDataPoint(myData d)
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.Invoke(new Action<myData>(this.AddDataPoint), new object[] { d });
            }
            else
            {
                chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(d.X, d.Y);
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(worker)).Start(new Action<myData>(this.AddDataPoint));
        }
        private void worker(object obj)
        {
            var _delegate = (Action<myData>)obj;
            for (int x = 0; x < 50; x++)
            {
                _delegate(new myData { X = x, Y = 2 * x });
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
    public class myData
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;
    }
}
```

Comment: So i need to have handle of form class inside worker thread (algo class) ? And what does the first block this.Invoke(..) part means ?

Comment: Why we need 2 references (form and delegate) ? So i will pass only a reference of delegate to algo class.  This delegate is defined in the Form class, right ? What is first this.invoke(new Action..) doing ?

Comment: mhh, i need more coffee. of course you only need the delegate. the invoke creates a new Action<T> delegate (void(T)) and requests the UI thread to call it (or whatever thread is managed by the ISynchronizedInvoke implementation... in case of a Form it's the UI thread)

Comment: Please check my Edit. Am i doing wrong ? I added exact code. the cross thread problem is still there after doing your suggestion.

Comment: either replace "_chart.chartDelegate" in the invoke call with "this.AddTickToChart" or apply the test for InvokeRequired directly to your public void AddTick() in the chart class...  and make sure that the chart control is instanced by the UI thread (e.g. in the forms ctor)

Comment: currently invoke is happening in Form.AddTickToChart. How can i add this.AddTickToChart again inside. And AddTick itself is delegate in chart class what can i achieve by invoke test inside it. Invoke needs a delegate, which delegate will i refer then ?. It is already being called inside a delegate. Some confusion is there.  :-(

Comment: ok ... to solve confusion, let's start over ... try the example Form

Comment: ok. cross thread problem goes. but the chart window (MyFOrm is separate window) shows up blank and unresponsive. thanks. I guess now my problem is to deal with Form windows and UI controls. I am not expert on those. Can u tell what i may be missing in InitializeCOmponent or so. I cant even make out if my data points are being drawn in the chart. I just did chart.Show() in MyFOrm_buttonCLick.

Comment: ok got it working as seperate your code.  :)  I think with my code the chart is showing blank etc. that is the chart control usage specific problem. I shifted all runner code to new project to plug into this working chart.