# UI or tool to review charts data

Tags: c#, charts, recording

I am building a software to test my machine and collect data from it. My software now can show 7 information (4 chats and 3 bitmaps)with respect to time. However, all the data can only be observed in real time as shown in figure and I lost all of them when I pause the timer.  How can I review all these data(4 chats and 3 bitmaps) in the way of recording? For example, I want to have a bar to check the past data like a movie player as shown in figure 2.

[image: Software interface]
[image: This is the function of displaying data]

Comment: How about adding classes and saving the data to the instantiated objects?

Comment: The fastest way would be index-sequential files, but SQL table with proper clustered index by Time and IndicatorId would perform well. You can store years of historical data like this.

Comment: Make an estimate of how many data you expect! Decide if they should persist the program run! Add the results to the question!

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal Do you have any C# code or examples can provide? I still not understand what exactly should I do to achieve this task.

Comment: @TaW I get 24X3 data per 20ms. So if I want to record 15mins and review them. The data set would be really large.

Comment: That would be 45k records for 15 minutes. What does 24x3 mean? bytes? characters? doubles? Depending, of course on that record size and your machine, you still could hold that amount in memory..

Comment: @TaW Thanks for your quick reply. I am really new to C#. My machine has 24 sensors receiving pressure level and I have 3 machines, so 24X3. How can hold this in memory? But I don't want to merely hold an amount of data only. What I want is displaying the result in chart and bitmap forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you store your historical data in SQL database, the design would look something like this:

[image: SampleUML]

The important part is to have well designed the table with all the historical values, use composite clustered index by `IndicatorID` & `Time`. SQL Server example:

```
CREATE TABLE [PenData](
    [IndicatorID] smallint NOT NULL,
    [Time] datetime2(0) NOT NULL,
    [Value] real NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Data] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IndicatorID] ASC,
    [Time] ASC
))
```

In [MS Charts controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456753.aspx) you can have a scrollbar with the chart that can do Zoom In and Zoom Out:

```
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = false;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.Enabled = true;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.Size = 20;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
```

So you create another control on a form, that controls what data are loaded from database to the chart (which day etc.) - like your playback control - and you can allow user to futher zoom the loaded data as neccessary. In Windows `perfmon` application uses this functionality. You can zoom in and out charts from your code as well, e.g. by user specified time range.

---

If you want playback the data as if they were collected, you will need to add a timer to create the feel of real-time data playback - suppose you need it because you need to animate images, otherwise it is better to display it interactively.

So you do the same as if you were displaying the data in the realtime, but instead of getting values from your sensors you read them from database.

There is an example here for MS Charts: [Need help on Problem in using c# .net 4.0 realtime chart in windows form application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5652533/2224701)

Comment: Really thanks for your help. I think I get the logic you proposed. But I still can't understand how can I playback the bitmaps and charts at the same location on my software. Is it adding a playback control which can load numerical data and then add then back to the functions of charts and bitmaps? So I can have a playback alike tool now?

Comment: I see, you want to play it with animation like a movie...? Normaly user just zooms in on the data of interest like in perfmon. I will add a small example.